# Need to get file name, line number, match position of a pattern in a file

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

I have a requirement where I have to get the file name, line number, match position (byte offset) of a pattern in a file.

I am using the `grep` command for this and so far am able to get the file name and line number without issues, but un able to get the match position on each line individually.

There is a `-b` option in `grep` which gives byte offset but its not giving result for each line individually.

Tried below:

```
grep --with-filename -n -r -E -o "pattern" file.txt
```

This gives file name and line number along with match line.

```
grep --with-filename -n -r -E -o -b "pattern" file.txt
```

This gives byte offset (position of match in line) but it is considering whole file as a single line and giving result, but I need position result for each line starting with that line not beginning of file.

Eg: file.txt

```
abc
def
xyzva
```

Search pattern: a

Expected result:

```
file.txt:1:0:abc
file.txt:3:4:xyzva
```

If there is any other solution in Python for the same, that too is acceptable.

Comment: Why is this tagged for Python?

Comment: If there is a solution in python for the requirement, am ok with that too...

Comment: There is a solution in Python. It's trivial

Comment: I can work with that, could you add the solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with position starting with `1` (as opposed to `0`), you can use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

```bash
$ cat ip.txt
abc
def
xyzva

$ rg -H --column --no-heading 'a' ip.txt
ip.txt:1:1:abc
ip.txt:3:5:xyzva
```

You can use `awk` for a more customizable solution:

```bash
$ awk 'match($0, /a/){print FILENAME, NR, RSTART, $0}' OFS=: ip.txt
ip.txt:1:1:abc
ip.txt:3:5:xyzva

$ awk 'match($0, /a/){print FILENAME, NR, RSTART-1, $0}' OFS=: ip.txt
ip.txt:1:0:abc
ip.txt:3:4:xyzva
```